# ¿Se puede declarar una función dentro de otra función en python?

Tags: python, function

me preguntaba si podria crearse una función que contenga otra función dentro de si en python o tengo que crear una clase. Quedaría algo asi:

```
def prueba1():
  WSDL = "a"
  def accion(string):
    print string
    return None
  return None
def prueba2():
  WSDL = "b"
  def accion (string):
    print string
    return None
  return None
```

¿o para poder hacer esto o prueba1() tendria que ser una clase?

En mi codigo tengo un cliente SOAP que creo con 3 archivos WSDL diferentes, dependiendo de que funciones necesite. Cada WSDL tiene 4 funciones para obtener el valor que quieras obtener de servidor.

Por reducir el tamaño del codigo no creo un cliente en cada función, sino que tengo una funcion donde creo que SOAP con WSDL que necesito y luego defino el resto de funciones para obtener el valor.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad, porque quieres hacer eso??

Comment: He editado la pregunta, asi puede que queda más clara

Comment: Como añadido, deberías echar un ojo a los principios SOLID, con esta forma de programar estás violando el primero de estos principios, el principio de **RESPONSABILIDAD ÚNICA**, son muy interesantes y te darán una visión más estructurada a la hora de programar, te dejo un enlace. Saludos. https://www.genbetadev.com/paradigmas-de-programacion/solid-cinco-principios-basicos-de-diseno-de-clases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si que puedes declarar una función dentro de otra función, solo ten en cuenta que la vida de esa función es esfímera al pertenecer al ámbito de la función donde es definida. **Va a ser creada de nuevo cada vez que llames a la función donde es creada y dejará de existir cuando esta retorne**. Esto implica que no podrá ser llamada desde fuera de la función donde es definida en principio.

Dada lo anterior, son pocos los casos en los que esto es útil, principalmente en clausuras y factory-functions (aparte de por razones de limpieza y encapsulamiento del código). En todo caso su uso está restringido a ser llamada por la función "raiz":

```
def foo():
    #Intentamos llamr a bar antes de que sea creada
    try:
        bar()
    except:
        print('Soy "foo" intentando llamar a "bar" antes de ser creada, no se puede.')

    #Declaramos bar dentro de foo
    def bar():
        print('Hola soy "bar".')

    #Intentamos llamar a bar de nuevo
    print('Hola soy "foo" llamando a "bar" de nuevo.')
    bar()

#Llamamos a foo
foo()

#Intentamos llamar a bar desde fuera de foo
try:
    bar()
except:
    print('No he podido llamar a "bar" desde fuera de "foo".')
```

**Salida:**

> Soy "foo" intentando llamar a "bar" antes de ser creada, no se puede.
>   Hola soy "foo" llamando a "bar" de nuevo.
>   Hola soy "bar".
>   No he podido llamar a "bar" desde fuera de "foo".

Comment: Pero claro yo no puedo llamara directamente a bar no? ¿no puedo hacer una especie de foo().bar()? ¿Para eso necesito crear una clase? Porque realmente al llamar a foo().bar() yo lo que quiero es pasar por foo() y llegar a bar()

Comment: Efectivamente, esa función solo existe desde que es creada por foo hasta que foo retorna. Fuera de la función foo bar no existe. Crea una clase para esto. Las clases permiten precisamente eso, crear patrones reutilizables. Si necesitas que entre un objeto y otro, bar sea diferente en algo, pues la sobreescribes. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, utilizo clases entonces. Muchas gracias otra vez!

Comment: @Alex Hombre, por poder... Python es muy flexible. Las funciones pueden tener "atributos" que les hace parecerse un poco en apariencia a una clase. Puedes usar uno de esos atributos para que apunte a la función interna y así poder usarla desde fuera. Aquí tienes un [totalmente desaconsejable ejemplo](https://repl.it/repls/RecentVioletredTrialsoftware) Fijate que el texto que está imprimiendo `bar` es el que pasaste a `foo`!! (esta es la idea de _clausura_, que la función interna puede acceder a variables o parámetros de la externa).